# Android services ! How to keep a service running even if the application is closed

Tags: android, background-service

I would like to create an application that wakes up on shake, once the sensors are activated by shaking the app should be launched (the application is initially not activated). I have implemented a background service which detects the shaking movements and opens a new page but i didn't succeed to make it work when the app is off ( removed from the background running applications) Any Ideas please

Comment: I guess You need to use Intent Service